# FullStory Hauser not connecting to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, fullstory

FullStory has [Hasuer](https://github.com/fullstorydev/hauser) that lets you send data from FullStory to BigQuery, and seems pretty straightforward except it's not connecting with BigQuery when I update the config with

```
[bigquery]
Project = "myProject"
Dataset = "myDataset"
ExportTable = "fs_export"
SyncTable = "fs_sync"
# The amount of time after which the partitions will expire
# Valid time units are "s", "m", "h" (seconds, minutes, hours).
# For example, "720h" would expire the partitions after 30 days.
# If this value is omitted or "0", then the partitions will not expire.
PartitionExpiration = "0"
```

I get an error that says `>The requested URL <code>/bigquery/v2/projects//datasets//tables?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`

Which is making me believe it's not finding my project, and I don't see any further documentation on what's needed to connect to BQ. I've tried the project name, id, even tried incorporating the `ancestry` piece into the name to see if it needed that. But nothing changes that error message.

I thought there might be some auth setting i need to configure in BigQuery but even if i create a user, I don't see anywhere in this [example config](https://github.com/fullstorydev/hauser/blob/master/example-config.toml) to place those credentials.

Anyone successfully moving data from FullStory to BigQuery via this Hauser app and have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Update on this - had a senior member on my team help me debug.

My hypothesis was right - it was an issue with auth. You need to go to your service user on your VM and make sure it has:

- BigQuery Admin role
- Storage Object Admin role

Also, you *do* need to configure GCS and set up a bucket, then specify the name of that in the config file.

Config should look like this

```
[bigquery]
Project = "myProject"
Dataset = "myDataset"
ExportTable = "fs_export"
SyncTable = "fs_sync"
# The amount of time after which the partitions will expire
# Valid time units are "s", "m", "h" (seconds, minutes, hours).
# For example, "720h" would expire the partitions after 30 days.
# If this value is omitted or "0", then the partitions will not expire.
PartitionExpiration = "0"

[gcs]
Bucket="myBucket"
```

Hope this helps someone else!